# Dictionary Update Sequence Error with Tensorflow + FastAPI

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, pickle, fastapi

I have a tensorflow model on Google Colab, and whenever I run it locally I am able to make predictions. However when I pass the same dataframe after it is deployed on FastAPI, I get the error

```
INFO:     Started server process [283]
INFO:uvicorn.error:Started server process [283]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Waiting for application startup.
Public URL: NgrokTunnel: "https://f287-35-238-142-115.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:10000"
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:10000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:uvicorn.error:Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:10000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 68ms/step
INFO:     54.86.50.139:0 - "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 152, in jsonable_encoder
    data = dict(obj)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 157, in jsonable_encoder
    data = vars(obj)
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 394, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 255, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 152, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 117, in jsonable_encoder
    encoded_value = jsonable_encoder(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 160, in jsonable_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors) from e
ValueError: [ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
ERROR:uvicorn.error:Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 152, in jsonable_encoder
    data = dict(obj)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 157, in jsonable_encoder
    data = vars(obj)
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 394, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 255, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 152, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 117, in jsonable_encoder
    encoded_value = jsonable_encoder(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 160, in jsonable_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors) from e
ValueError: [ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:uvicorn.error:Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [283]
INFO:uvicorn.error:Finished server process [283]
```

I understand this error has to do with the dimensionality of my input, but when I pass the same exact dataframe before the model is deployed, the model can make predictions successfully.

```
import pickle

Pkl_Filename = "model_tree.pkl"  

with open(Pkl_Filename, 'wb') as file:  
    pickle.dump(NN_model, file)
```

NN_Model is my tensorflow model.

```
  class Music(BaseModel):
    SRC: float 
    CN: float 
    DS: float 
    AGE: float 
    MKE: float 
    MDL: float 
    CS: float 
    FB: float
    CB: float
    M: float 
    VC: float
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "SRC": 1, 
                "CN": 215, 
                "DS": 16.0,
                "AGE": 34,
                "MKE": 13,
                "MDL": 399,
                "CS": 16,
                "FB": 1,
                "CB": 9,
                "M": 4,
                "VC": 4

            }
        }



from fastapi import FastAPI
import pickle

app = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("startup")
def load_model():
    global model
    model = pickle.load(open("model_tree.pkl", "rb"))

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return {'message': 'This is the homepage of the API '}

@app.post('/predict')
def get_music_category(data: Music):
    received = data.dict()
    SRC = received['SRC']
    CN = received['CN']
    DS = received['DS']
    AGE = received['AGE']
    MKE = received['MKE']
    MDL = received['MDL']
    CS = received['CS']
    FB = received['FB']
    CB = received['CB']
    M = received['M']
    VC = received['VC']



    temp_list = [SRC, CN, DS, AGE, MKE, MDL, CS, FB, CB, M, VC]


    # temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_list).transpose()
    # temp_df = temp_df.astype(float)
    temp_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(x, name=f'column_{i}') for i,x in enumerate(temp_list)], axis=1)

    # df = pd.read_json(temp_df)
    pred_name = model.predict(temp_df)


    return {'prediction': pred_name}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share the full traceback, not just the error.

Comment: @M.O. I attached the traceback

Comment: What is the data type of `pred_name`? It's probably something FastAPI can't serialize (maybe a Pandas DataFrame?), ao to resolve this, it should be converted to a dictionary.